# ReactJS styled component (tooltip) shows in wrong position

Tags: reactjs, components, position, tooltip

I am working on a web for text data tagging.
When I dragged something (word) , I want the tooltip appear just right below dragged text.
but it shows in wrong position.
[tooltip shows in wrong position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFs6z.png)

I am using a Tag Editor Component with antd like this.

```
{
    title: 'Sentence',
    dataIndex: 'sentence',
    key: 'sentence',

render: (text, record, index) => (
    // text === record.sentence
    <div onClick = {onClick}>
        <TagEditor value={text} tags={tags} onChange={onChange}/>
    </div>

    )
}
```

and here is my Tag Editor Component's function that positioning the tooltip.

```
function onSelectText(event) {
    const clientRects = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).getClientRects()[0];

    if (clientRects) {
        setTooltipPosition({ x: (clientRects.left + clientRects.right) / 2, y: clientRects.bottom })

        const parentNode = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).startContainer.parentNode;
        const tagIndex = tags.findIndex(tag => tag.name === parentNode.id);

        if (tagIndex > -1) {
            const newTags = tags.map((tag, index) => index === tagIndex ? { ...tag, checked: true } : { ...tag, checked: false });
            setTags(newTags);
        } else {
            const newTags = tags.map(tag => {
                tag.checked = false;
                return tag;
            });

            setTags(newTags);
        }

        const selectText = window.getSelection().toString();

        if (selectText.length > 0) {
            setShowTooltip(true);
        } else {
            setShowTooltip(false);
        }
    }
};
```

The position ( x, y ) of tooltips appear as I intended in the chrome devtools, but it shows in wrong position..

I would be grateful if anyone can help.

Comment: Can you put that code in a sandbox so we can see your full implementation and debug it?

Comment: @Domino987 https://codesandbox.io/s/cw52l here it is.

Comment: It works for me ;) What browser are you using?

Comment: @Domino987 I am using Chrome.. 
Does the tooltip appear properly in your environment?

Comment: @Domino987 
Would you like to try the ones under the MultipleSentencesTable other than the three editors above?

Comment: Yes the upper one work but the multiple sentence do not.

Comment: Yeah..that's the problem I have..what should I do?